# Failed to find "nativescript-angular/platform", relative to:app/tns_modules/

Tags: android, node.js, platform, nativescript-angular

Next error appears when I execute: tns run android. The problem started after installing "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer" plugin and removing android platform.

```
System.err: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-angular/platform", relative to: app/tns_modules/
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1032)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5876)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1699)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/main.js', line: 4, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
```

My package.json looks:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.conFusion",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^5.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.3.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.2.7",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "^6.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.17.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.0.2",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

I removed and reinstalled hooks, platform and node modules directories but the error is still there. I don't know what could be my next step.